# Cannot re-install Microsoft Office after buying new version for new laptop

Tags: microsoft-word, installation, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

This has been a complete nightmare experience, I can't use PowerPoint or Word and I need to get some work done for next week.

Here's the gist:

- New laptop, Windows 10
- Alright, I started using office, cool, no problem first few weeks
- Eventually, Office stops letting me edit documents and asks me to enter an activation key
- I figure I need to buy the product, so I purchase: "Office Home & Student 2016 for PC". I get an email with an activation key, and a link to Install Office
- I get this error on their website from that Install link (from the email receipt of buying the above):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a58dU.png)

I don't remember ever having a subscription, I just buy new laptops periodically!! This is actually the first time I bought a Microsoft software product and I can't use it!

- I Google the error, nothing useful. Their support site says to go into my MS account, go under Services, and cancel old MS Office subscriptions (from my last laptop?). I see this:

[(Yes, I had an xbox live back in the day)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkTaU.png)

Clearly there's no option to cancel some existing subscription to Office which, if I did have, I had no idea and can't seem to find any evidence.

- Now the best part, customer support. I get a god damn CHAT BOT that's incredibly useless, even when I give it the exact error codes from above. Eventually it's pre-programmed questioning runs out, and it asks me if I want to talk to a human. YES I do! But... their phone call hours are closed.

This whole situation is ridiculous. The one time I pay M$ some money I can't use their product. Their user flow and customer support is absolutely atrocious.

Please someone help me get Office, I need to get some work done for next week :( It's very late and I need to go to sleep now.

Answer (score 1):

If it is true that you still have a subscription then go to your [Office Account here](https://stores.office.com/myaccount/home.aspx) where your current subscription should be listed. Press "Install" (or the main button showing under the current subscription). Now, if there are any devices that are using the current subscription listed underneath "Install Information" choose "Deactivate Install" Once you have deactivated all devices, go ahead and re- "Install"  that subscription.